# SSO - Client Certificate vs SAML

Tags: authentication, certificates, sso, saml

For me SSO is sign on where one need not type the password explicitly.

I see one of the possible way to achieve it is by using Certificates loaded in browser.

SAML/OAuth delegates the job of authentication to some IDP. As per my understanding these IDP in most cases use the certificates loaded in client browser to identify him/her.

I have following questions:
1) Why the web-sites doesn't use the client certificates directly.
2) If I have to pass the SAML token while calling the REST end point, how the header will look like eg. `Basic aTA2MTk1111pB43he3juh3` for Basic or `Bearer aTA2MTk1111pB43he3juh3` for OAuth